# Is there a way to configure size of /tmp in AWS for gluejob

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I know that you are able to configure Ephemeral Storage and increase the size of the /tmp directory with lambda, however is there a way to do this with Glue Job as well? Or if I have a Glue Job triggered by a lambda and I increase the Ephemeral Storage of that lambda, will that be the same instance of temp storage as the lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WorkerType in the Glue Job documentation, I think you can use a larger processing unit to get that larger disk allowable for your Glue's /tmp.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-job.html